# pandas finds indices of rows in each group which meets certain condition and assign values to these rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`,

```
name_id name
1       a
2       b
2       b
3       c
3       c
3       c
```

now I want to `groupby` `name_id` and assign `-1` to rows in the group(s), whose length is 1 or < 2;

```
    one_occurrence_indices = df.groupby('name_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1).index.tolist()

    for index in one_occurrence_indices:
        df.loc[index, 'name_id'] = -1
```

I am wondering what is the best way to do it. so the result `df`,

```
name_id name
-1       a
 2       b
 2       b
 3       c
 3       c
 3       c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name_id')['name_id'].transform('size') == 1, 'name_id'] = -1
```

Alternative is [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['name_id'] = np.where(df.groupby('name_id')['name_id'].transform('size') == 1, 
                         -1, df['name_id'])

print (df)
   name_id name
0       -1    a
1        2    b
2        2    b
3        3    c
4        3    c
5        3    c
```

Also if want test duplicates use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['name_id'] = np.where(df.duplicated('name_id', keep=False), df['name_id'], -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.name_id*=(df.groupby('name_id').name.transform(len)==1).map({True:-1,False:1})
df
Out[50]: 
   name_id name
0       -1    a
1        2    b
2        2    b
3        3    c
4        3    c
5        3    c
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
lens = df.groupby('name_id')['name'].transform(len)

df['name_id'].mask(lens < 2, -1, inplace=True)

print(df)

   name_id name
0       -1    a
1        2    b
2        2    b
3        3    c
4        3    c
5        3    c
```